# PostgreSQL not showing up on phpconfig() function(on windows)

Tags: php, postgresql

I just installed Apache 2.2.11 and downloaded the zip for PHP5.2.9-2

I uncommented

> extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll

and

> extension=php_pgsql.dll

But when I call the phpinfo() function, postgresql is not showing up. What am I forgetting?

Also, on the PHP site, I found this:

> In order to enable PostgreSQL support,
>   --with-pgsql[=DIR] is required when you compile PHP. DIR is the PostgreSQL
>   base install directory, defaults to
>   /usr/local/pgsql. If shared object
>   module is available, PostgreSQL module
>   may be loaded using extension
>   directive in php.ini or dl() 
>   function.
>   I recognise that this is ment for Linux, but is there something written here, telling me to do something I've forgotten?

Comment: No. But that's not even needed. phpinfo() shows the info of the DLL's it finds, no of installed database systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `php.ini` make sure that the `extension_dir` directive is pointing to the folder that contains the php_pgsql.dll file.

Also check your HTTP error log for errors.

Comment: Didn't do that yet. I've now set the extension_dir to "C:\php\ext", but no effect yet. Gonna go check those logs.

Answer (score 2):

Did you restart Apache after making changes to your php.ini? The PHP module in Apache wont pickup changes until a restart is performed.

Comment: I know, most basic of things.

Answer (score 0):

You still need the 'client library' portion of pgsql in order to load php_pgsql.dll or php_pdo_pgsql.dll. Also, for future reference, you can use a tool like [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to load the PHP dll files and see the missing runtime linkage.